# Change Tab in AngularJS Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to change tab in AngularJS controler?

My HTML look like this:

```
<tabset justified="true">
<tab heading="Tab1">Content</tab>
<tab heading="Tab2">Content</tab>
<tab heading="Tab3">Content</tab>
</tabset>
<button ng-click=switchTab(1)">
```

How to write switchTab function?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score -1):

Use the `active` attribute.

```
<tab heading="Tab Heading" active="expression">Tab Content</tab>
```

Your function will switch to a tab if `active` evaluates to a true value.